# Understanding quantum cosmology

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor

As I understand it there have been different attempts to use Loop Quantum Gravity to make a theory of cosmology. The first one being done by Martin Bojowald and then later one being performed by Ashtekar, Pawloski and Singh. There is a description of what they did in their paper that was different to previous attempts but as a non cosmologist Im struggling to understand it. Is there anyone that can translate this into laymen terms?

I have the passage below and understand that a metric is a mathematical object used in relativity to encode the gravitational field. But I don't get what they mean by "kinematic 3 metric" and " physical metric". If anyone could explain these terms Id be very grateful Anyway here is the passage:

> Roughly, at a key step in the procedure, the Hamiltonian constraint operator of [45] implicitly used a kinematic 3-metric $q^{*}ab$ defined by the co-moving coordinates rather than the physical metric $q_{ab} = a^2$$q^{*}_{ab}$ (where $a$ is the scale factor). When this is corrected, the new, improved Hamiltonian constraint again resolves the singularity and, at the same time, is free from all three drawbacks of the $\mu_{0}$ scheme."

From the following paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0893

Comment: Hi Harry: have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5163 for physical metric

Comment: Thanks, so am i correct to a say that physical metric has a measurable speed of light whereas a non physical metric has an imaginary speed of light? What about this phrase "kinematic 3 metric" any idea what that is?

Comment: This is on page 11. Please at this to the reference.

Comment: Thanks Semoni , but not sure how that answers the question.